# Write on the screen the array up to a word, using filter - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array with two clickable options inside it to complete a sentence (This array I put on the screen by an innerHTML). These options are within [], I just need to type on the screen until the end of a [], leaving the second option in the screen to continue the selection, always concatenating with the phrase.

**(This all has to be done in the "showArrayConsole", and please don't touch the selection jquery)**

I have already tried to separate the arrays, leaving each option in some array, but I can not do that. It is all within an array only, inside it can have several phrases, countless options.

Code:

```js
var exame = new Array("Exame realizado no ombro ", 
  "[", 
  " esquerdo ",
  "direito ",
  "]",
  ", foi ",
  "[",
  " acima ", 
  "abaixo ", 
  "]."
);

document.getElementById("loop").innerHTML = exame.join("")

function showArrayConsole(s) {
  document.getElementById("loop").innerHTML = (exame[0] + s);
}

$("p").click(function(e) {
  s = window.getSelection();
  console.log(s);
  var range = s.getRangeAt(0);
  console.log(range);
  var node = s.anchorNode;
  while (range.toString().indexOf(' ') != 0) {
    range.setStart(node, (range.startOffset - 1));
  }
  range.setStart(node, range.startOffset + 1);
  do {
    range.setEnd(node, range.endOffset + 1);

  } while (range.toString().indexOf(' ') == -1 && range.toString().trim() != '');

  var str = range.toString().trim();
  s.removeAllRanges();
  alert(str);
  showArrayConsole(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="loop"></p>
```

Comment: Use a SO runnable snippet to provide a simple demo, it will help you to get an answer faster.

Comment: You don't seem to have any use for jQuery here. You only wrapped a `p` tag with it. Plus one of your while loop seems to be an infinite loop